# iOS full screen background image for all screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to set a background image for my app that will scale to fill the 4, 4.7, and 5.5 inch screens.

- I'm working in XCode 6 with swift
- I created a 640 x 1136 image, and pasted @1x, @2x, and @3x images in my images.xcasetts folder. I selected the 'scale to fill' mode for the image view.
- I created a UIImage in the main.storyboard file for the 4 inch screen.  This image fills the screen just fine when I build.
- I think I've tried just about every combination of height / width / aspect ratio constraints with no luck.

Comment: Did you add autolayout constraints for the `UIImage`?

Comment: You didn't mention what the problem is. You'll probably want to set constraints on the UIImageView so it grows or shrinks with the various screen sizes.

Comment: 640 x 1136 is the size of 2x 4" screen. This resolution does not fit iPhone 6, iPhone 6+. Stretching the image would result a blurry result.

Comment: @Koen I tried adding various combinations of height / width / aspect ratio constraints, but that only resulted in a strange scaling of the image without it filling the screen.

Comment: @EricS Problem: I can get the image to fill the 4" screen, but I cannot get it to scale to fill the 4.7 or 5.5" screens.

Answer (score 10):

The 4 and 4.7 use @2x, 5.5 used @3x, please see the screenshot detail.

[image: Screenshot]

You can download the PDF that is the origin of this screenshot from [Ugur Akdemir's Dribble](https://dribbble.com/shots/1721368-New-iPhone-Design-Guide?list=searches&tag=free&offset=77).

Comment: Then please explain what image dimensions would be: (for iOS >=7)? And keep it mind that iOS >= 7 can be installed on iPhone 4, 5, 6 & 6 Plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution: http://codemotionapps.com/get-assets-ready-ios8-iphone-6-plus/

[image: .]

I created vector gradient in free Inkscape editor and export to PDF (my PDF file size is 4Kb). Then I add this PDF to Images.xcassets in my project and selected it. In Attributes inspector for Scale Factors choose Single Vector. When the app is compiled the PDF generates PNGs for all nesesery resolutions @1x, @2x, @3x and others :-)